# How can I use an ID tag on my responsive css?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm currently having issues making my image responsive on my site. I can get it to work on fiddle, but not my page.

Here is the fiddle code

- JSFiddle

Css:

```
div.imggg img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="imgg">
<img src="http://studio2d3d.com/wp-
content/uploads/2017/06/ShampooAd_Timeline.gif" width="200" height="200">
</div>
```

MY Page
Html:

```
<div class="boldgrid-section">
<div class="container">
<div id="cf" class="imggg">
<p class="mod-reset"><img class="bottom" src="http://studio2d3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/FemalePortrait2_E.jpg" style="width: 80%; max-width: 600px;"></p>
<p class="mod-reset"><img class="top" src="http://studio2d3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/FemalePortrait2_OG.jpg" style="width: 80%; max-width: 600px;"></p>
</div>
</div>
<h2 class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 color1-color">
</h2>
<div class="container"><div class="row" style="padding-top: 45px;">
</div></div>
</div>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You are using inline styles on your images. Inline styles have a higher specificity than IDs and Classes and therefore will override your `div.imggg img` selector. Either remove the inline styles (ideal) or use `!important` (avoid if possible) in your CSS to override the inline styles. There's also a possibility of `.mod-reset`, `.bottom` or `.top` affecting things, depending on which properties were defined.

Answer (score 0):

Inline Styles have higher precedence over external styles, Declare those inline styles with the external styles.
Since you are using bootstrap, i will suggest you set an image class on the image to

```
img-responsive
```